# Changing HTML Table Formatting When Exporting from R

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, html, r

I am generating several tables in R and then exporting them to HTML(5). For instance:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R-org* :results output raw :exports results
  df <- data.frame(x=0.110, y=0.132)
  rownames(df) <- "Rates"
  print(ascii(df, header=TRUE, colnames=colnames(df), rownames=rownames(df),
              digits=3, caption="Rates"),
        type="org")
#+END_SRC
```

This seems to work well enough, but it creates very ugly tables. How do I assign HTML attributes (as shown with the `#+ATTR_HTML` line in [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html)) from the R block?

Comment: Where does the `ascii()` function come from?

Comment: found it, the `ascii` package, as it turns out.

Comment: It's a function from the `R` `ascii` package that prints raw `org-mode` formatted tables (among other formats). For other examples see [this page](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html#orgheadline11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this from the R side:

```
* Test this

** Original
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R-org* :results output raw :exports results
  library(ascii)
  df <- data.frame(x=0.110, y=0.132)
  rownames(df) <- "Rates"
  print(ascii(df, header=TRUE, colnames=colnames(df), rownames=rownames(df),
              digits=3, caption="Rates"),
        type="org")
#+END_SRC


** Formatted
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R-org* :results output raw :exports results
  library(ascii)
  df <- data.frame(x=0.110, y=0.132)
  rownames(df) <- "Rates"
  cat("#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border\n")
  print(ascii(df, header=TRUE, colnames=colnames(df), rownames=rownames(df),
              digits=3, caption="Rates"),
        type="org")
#+END_SRC
```

That's a bit ugly. It would be neater if the author of the `ascii` provided a `header` argument that allowed you to explicitly add an org-mode header in the call to `ascii`. (they do provide a `header` argument, but it serves another purpose). That may be a reasonable feature request.

Comment: That is ugly, but it works. I will submit a feature request. Thanks!

Comment: I missed a `\n` in the cat() statement that is important! Edited to correct

Comment: Alternatively, it would be easy to write your own wrapper function in R that would bundle the cat() statement and the ascii output for you.

Comment: That is what I am thinking. Isolate the ugly stuff.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple HTML exporting R tables from Org-mode

Perhaps you can try `:results output value` , `:colnames yes :rownames yes`.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R-org* :results output value :exports results :colnames yes :rownames yes
df <- data.frame(x=0.110, y=0.132)
rownames(df) <- "Rates"
df
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
|       |    x |     y |
|-------+------+-------|
| Rates | 0.11 | 0.132 |
```

### HTML Exporting with Captions and Labels

If you need captions or reference labels,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R-org* :results output value :exports results :colnames yes :rownames yes
df <- data.frame(x=0.110, y=0.132)
rownames(df) <- "Rates"
df
#+END_SRC

#+CAPTION: Rates
#+NAME: TABLE-TMP-01
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border
#+RESULTS:
|       |    x |     y |
|-------+------+-------|
| Rates | 0.11 | 0.132 |
```

Now we have a reference for Table `[[TABLE-TMP-01]]`.